# Spanned and Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the space spanned by vector  ${\begin{bmatrix}  3t  & 2+5t\end{bmatrix}}^T$, where t ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ is a valid vector space.

The T stand for the transpose of that vector. So kindly help me out in this problem. What will be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand what you mean, the answer is ‘No’, because, for instance:
$$[3t,2+5t]+[3u,2+5u]=[3(t+u,\color{red}{4}+5(t+u).$$

However it is an *affine space*, i.e.  it is the vector space $\{t(3,5)\mid t\in\mathbf R\}$ *translated  by the vector* $(0,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

to be  a valid vector space it has to satisfy addition/subtraction/scalar multiplication all these are also part of same space, does this hold for the space spanned by the vector?